# Where can I find professional insights into the impact of DevOps upon SecOps?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, continuous-deployment

I'm writing about the arrival of DevOps practices such as continuous integration (CI) and continuous delivery (CD) and their impact upon SecOps (or whatever the equivalent team was called). My audiences are SecOps and DevOps professionals who are familiar with industry tools and terminology.

I'm looking for a resource, such as interviews with Security professionals, that describe the impact this had upon security practices. Specifically, the context would be small to medium-sized organizations (approximately 25 to 5000 FTEs) with one or more dedicated software development teams that reorganized as DevOps and implemented CI/CD.

Also, if you would like to share your experiences, I would appreciate hearing about them here. Please describe the organization at a high level; which DevOps practices were adopted/discontinued; which SecOps practices were adopted/discontinued; and particularly any key challenges and how they were overcome.

I know some SE groups are sensitive about receiving open-ended questions like this. However, I think it would be valuable for other visitors to read about and generalize from your professional experiences. If you feel like this question should be placed in a different forum, please let me know and I'll be glad to move it there.

Comment: Probably [related](http://devops.stackexchange.com/q/686/13) (at least for background)

Answer (score 4):

As alluded to by [Tensibai ♦](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/13/tensibai), I think the answers you are looking for start from my answer to "[What is SecOps?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/686/what-is-secops)", specifically from the "Further Reading" section:

- [DevOpsSec by Jim Bird](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/devopssec/9781491971413/)
- [DevSecCon: A DevSecOps Conference](http://www.devseccon.com/)
- [Velocity EU: Continuous Security](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/velocity-2016-/9781491958537/video290680.html)

Of the above I am currently reading Jim Bird's book, have had the pleasure of working with [the organiser](https://www.linkedin.com/in/francoisraynaud) of DevSecCon in a previous role and had the privilege of attending the Velocity Session in Amsterdam last year.

I would advise you to reach out to [Francois Raynaud](https://www.linkedin.com/in/francoisraynaud) and ask the question of him, he has worked in the space for a long time and is really helping the community evolve as part of DevOps.

Beyond my links, the O'Reilly Security Conference has published videos on Safari Books Online:

- 2016

  - [New York, NY](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/the-oreilly-security/9781491960035/)
  - [Amsterdam, Netherlands](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/oreilly-security-conference/9781491976128/)
  - [San Francisco, California](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/search/?query=Security%20Conference&highlight=true&is_academic_institution_account=false&extended_publisher_data=true&include_orioles=true&source=user&include_courses=true&sort=relevance)