# What is DataOps?

Tags: terminology, data

This site already has great answers for questions like What is [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/what-is-devops) and what is [SecOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/686/what-is-secops).

Over time, I have come to be of [the opinion](https://imgflip.com/s/meme/Change-My-Mind.jpg) that DevOps was born when the philosophy of the Agile methodology was applied to Operations. Similarly so with SecOps.

What then would be DataOps - applying agile methods to Big Data & Data Analytics look like? How is this similar to agile software development and DevOps and where might it be different?

Comment: Can you give us some evidence that DataOps is actually a thing? has it been mentioned in blogs/papers/conferences? Does it have synonyms? Thanks :)

Comment: The biggest points of difference would be that with 'DataOps', that is presumably going to very tied to managing state. But I could imagine that it could be understood to be tied to concepts such as data-streaming and event-sourcing. A world of possibilities.

Comment: @BruceBecker - it has a [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DataOps) and a [manifesto](https://www.dataopsmanifesto.org/) and also made [Oracle's Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/datascience/what-is-dataops-everything-you-need-to-know)

Comment: Could you update the question so it is not "primarily opinion-based" anymore? Please let us know when you have updated the question.

Comment: @030 - I'm not quite sure how this feels primarily opinion based. Could you elaborate on why you feel that way and what this question would look like if it wasn't? How is this question worded differently than the "What is DevOps / What is SecOps" questions that runs afoul of this guideline?

Comment: @JamesShewey Yes you are right. I will reopen the question.

Answer (score 2):

> Over time, I have come to be of the opinion that DevOps was born when
>   the philosophy of the Agile methodology was applied to Operations.
>   Similarly so with SecOps.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) indicates that Agile software development is about "early delivery", "adaptive planning" and "rapid and flexible response to change". In order to deliver early, automation is key in DevOps.

> What then would be DataOps - applying agile methods to Big Data & Data
>   Analytics look like?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DataOps), DataOps tries to incorporate DevOps best practices to enhance data analytics.

> How is this similar to agile software development and DevOps and where
>   might it be different?

**Similar**

- Quick action on change
- Fail fast
- Adaptation
- Tools & platforms: ansible, terraform, AWS, GCP, AKS, EKS

**Differences**

- Focus on BigData
- Knowledge about NoSQL Hadoop, Hbase, Cassandra, MongoDB needed
- How to tune relational database like postgres, mysql that contains large amount of data
- More emphasize on bigdata tools like Spark

Answer (score -1):

The ultimately goals of **agile** and **DevOps** are the same - to improve the speed and quality of software development see the following articles which give a better understanding  -

**Atlassian :** [DevOps vs Agile](https://www.atlassian.com/devops/what-is-devops/agile-vs-devops)

**PhoenixNAP:**  [Head to head comparison](https://phoenixnap.com/blog/devops-vs-agile)

Comment: The question (title) is about DataOps, not "Agile" of "DevOps". So how does this answer answer address the original question?